# Would you help me to understand which result from Sobolev Spaces or PDE are being used here?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I've never studied PDE and I only studied a little about Sobolev Spaces by myself. I would like to understand why can I conclude that $u_{m,n}$ is a weak solution to the Dirichlet problem below. Is being used any theorem? Or is being used only a definition of a weak solution? or is it only a matter of developing calculations related to the previous inequality in 2.10? I also did not understand why there is an infimum before a maximum in (2.10), would be about any definition, or is being used any theorem?

**P.S:** I'm studying for my final project in my course however is very hard to understand many steps in the paper. Despite of this, I'm really enjoying everything I'm learning.

[image]

Where (2.6), (2.7) and (2.8) are

[image]

And, the functional $J_{m,n}$ being mentioned is

[image]

Comment: Try to calculate directional derivative first. Think of $\nabla$ as an ordinary linear operator.

Comment: I wonder what is the derivative of $(v_+)^q$.

Comment: @ArcticChar nothing else than $q(v^+)^{q-1}$ provided $q\ge1$ (assuming $v^+=\max(v,0)$).

Comment: Um.... I guess so. To the OP, you've got your $L_n'(v)$ wrong. Look like you just add $\varphi$ to the product and did not differentiate.

Comment: @daw I've included the answer I found. Would you please, check it for me?

Comment: Much better than the first trial. The second term is missing a $\phi$

Comment: humm, ok. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two theorems. The first theorem is the
[Mountain Pass Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_pass_theorem) , which tells you that if the functional $J_{m,n}$ satisfies the hypotheses (2.6) and (2.7), then it admits a critical point, that is , a point $u_{m,n}$ such that the derivative of the functional $J_{m,n}$ computed at $u_{m,n}$ is zero.
Then you are using another theorem that says that critical points of your functional are weak solutions of a partial differential equations, called the Euler Lagrange equations of your functional. You can find this derivation in the book by Evans “Partial differential equations”.

Comment: Are you Giovanni Leoni? I can't believe you're responding to me by here. Lol
I'm a fan of your book "A first course of Sobolev Spaces".
This book is helping all the time in my final project.
Thanks very much for your contributions!

Comment: Glad you like the book!